# MultiValueDictKeyError at /__debug__/render_panel/ "'store_id'

Tags: django-debug-toolbar

When I use django debug toolbar, I get the following error:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /__debug__/render_panel/
"'store_id'"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't call that. Debug toolbar should be on your page and should use it to get your debugging done.

Answer (score 0):

Got this error all of a sudden. Not sure what triggered it, but noticed the javascript was now requesting: `"GET /__debug__/render_panel/?%5Bobject+Object%5D= HTTP/1.1" 500`

Replicated by opening a console in Safari and Chrome and typing:

`new URLSearchParams({"a":1}).toString();`
which returns: `"%5Bobject+Object%5D="`

Was able to patch in toolbar.js with:

```
var url = djDebug.getAttribute('data-render-panel-url');
var url_params = new URLSearchParams();
url_params.append('store_id', store_id);
url_params.append('panel_id', this.className);
url += '?' + url_params.toString();
```

Issue link: https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar/issues/816